# simple sso solution or service(web) based on SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Is there any simple SSO(Single Sign-On) solution or service(web) based on SAML?

I just want to experience SSO function as a software or web-service simply.

I tried to use SSOCircle, but no idea to enroll service provider.

Plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some others:

- [Okta](http://www.okta.com)
- [Centrify](http://centrify.com)
- [Auth0](https://www.auth0.com)

**Disclaimer: I work for Auth0**.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
Can I ask you more about SAML?
I tried to use Okta service
And I want to get packet information about SAML spec(Assertion, Protocol, Binding.......)
Using SAML tracer(plugin of Firefox), I got Assertion xml document(in real SSO service) but couldn't get other spec.
Is there any method, tool or software to get Binding xml spec of SAML?

Comment: I don't know about Okta. But you can create an account in Auth0, create a new SAML Application and use the Debug button to see what SAML assertion we generate. You can then tweak the parameters of the SAML assertion right there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many out there if you search. Take a look at these ones.

1. http://www.onelogin.com/
2. http://www.cloudaccess.com/saas-sso/

Comment: Can I get more information about how to use those two web sites?
For example, I want to know inserted information like consumer URL when I add apps(e.g. google mail) on www.onelogin.com